# PHP: foreach limit 999 results

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach(array_slice(glob('/res/images/*.jpg'), 0, 999) as $filename)
```

is work fine but

```
foreach(array_slice(glob('/res/images/*.jpg'), 0, 1000) as $filename)
```

doesnt work. Where is I can change such limit?

Comment: Please expand on "doesn't work". What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: Not show result. Thinks and nothing happens. 999 response time 2 sec, 1000 not responce

Comment: Maybe a [memory overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12772851/1607098)? What about switching to [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/directoryiterator)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with simple(May be the better) manner like

```
$i = 0;
foreach(glob('/res/images/*.jpg') as $filename) {
   if($i++ <= 1000) {
       // Do the display
   } else {
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: For huge amount of possible files, I suggest to `break` in `else` block.

Comment: Thanks @PavelŠtěrba I have added it now.Actually I forgot it

Comment: Or to simplify slightly, put `if($i++ > 1000) { break; }` at the top of the function, saving the extra indenting. However, I suspect this won't solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
$max = 1000;
foreach(array_slice(glob('/res/images/*.jpg'), 0, $max) as $filename) {
   // Some code here
   if($i++ >= $max) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Shortest Way to do like so.

```
$i = 0;
foreach(array_slice(glob('/res/images/*.jpg'), 0, 1000) as $filename) {
   // Some code here
   if($i++ >= 1000) break;
}
```

I hope it will be helpful.